# change products display order through custom module in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

First of all I am new to Magento and tried to create a module in it. It displays some products and sort them in particular order base on a attribute .Here is the code of the block

```
class Your_Block_Name extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

    public function getProducts() {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', '1')
                ->addFieldToFilter('my_attribute', array("notnull" => true))
                ->setOrder('my_attribute', 'whatever is the order');             
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

And in the .phtml file I call the above function and display the products and everything worked fine. Here is the code of .phtml file

```
<?php
$product_collection = $this->getProducts($sort_order);
foreach ($product_collection as $product) {
  //your code
}  
?>
```

Now I need to place a link or a button or a dropdown in the template and after clicking that link/button/dropdown I want to change the order of display. I do not know how can I achieve this. I do not know how can I pass the value(s) from that link to BLOCK or controller so that it change the order of display. And I do not know what is the best possible way to achieve this.

By the way I am using Magento community version.

Answer (score 0):

used `->addAttributeToSort('attribute_code','sortorder')` instead of `setOrder()`.
`sortorder` should be `DESC` Or  `ASC`

and

```
public function getProducts($sortOrder='DESC') {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                ->addFieldToFilter('status', '1')
                ->addFieldToFilter('my_attribute', array("notnull" => true))
                ->addAttributeToSort('attribute_code',$sortOrder);             
        return $collection;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I need to pass the ASC or DESC value from template. And this I want to know how I can do it? A proper solution or reply will be better :)